# How do I replace keras.utils.multi_gpu_model for training with multiple gpus

Tags: tensorflow2.x

As of tensorflow 2.4 tensorflow.keras.utils.multi_gpu_model has been removed. I am looking for a way to replace this simple command to train with multiple gpus.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

model = load_model("my_model.h5")
if gpus>1:
    from tensorflow.keras.utils import multi_gpu_model
    model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=gpus)
```

Where model is a loaded model that can be used to train or make predictions on multiple gpus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to train with multiple gpus is to use a [distributed strategy](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/keras). The way I found that works pretty much as a drop in replacement is a [MirroredStrategy](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.2/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/MirroredStrategy)

```
session = MirroredStrategy()
with session.scope():
    model = load_model("my_model.h5")
```

This way when the model is used, inside of this block, it is used on multiple gpus.